# Convert a timestamp to ISO format date string

Tags: java, date

I have a logic in python that I am converting into Java code.
The logic is I need to read from a timestamp attribute in JSON file and convert it into ISO date format.
Python query:

```
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(jsonMsg["time"]).isoformat(timespec='seconds')
```

Here is the code I wrote in Java
1627065646.444 is an example of the value I get from JSON script

```
long timestamp = (long) 1627065646.444 * 1000;
        Timestamp time = new Timestamp(timestamp);
        Date d = new Date(time.getTime());

        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat();
        String dateToString = df.format(d);
        
        LocalDateTime datetime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateToString, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);
        ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.UTC;
        String formattedTimeStamp = datetime.atOffset(offset).toString();
```

When I run the code I get compile error "Text '7/23/21 11:40 AM' could not be parsed at index 0
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0"
This exception occurs at LocalDateTime.parse(dateToString, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME. Can someone please help me in understanding what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: @MartinZeitler same here...

Comment: The provided java code doesn't compile. The first line casts a String to a long which isn't how java works. You say: "I get the exception ... " - no, you don't. You'd get a compiler error. Please fix your question, paste the _actual_ code you have with the _actual_ error you get.

Comment: Sorry, my bad that was a typo. It is a compile error.  I will update the question.

Comment: I have also updated the code which I was trying on my dev box. I was using a constant value from the JSON for testing instead of reading from JSON to get the logic working first

Comment: [`final long nowMillis = (long) 1627065646.444 * 1000; System.out.println(Instant.ofEpochMilli(nowMillis));` will print `2021-07-23T18:40:46Z`](https://ideone.com/LLJ7bl) [(ISO 8601 format)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Comment: You are mixing old and modern. It’s a very bad idea. When you can use `LocalDateTime` and `ZoneOffset` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API, don’t also mix in the outdated and troublesome `Timestamp`, `Date`, `DateFormat` and `SimpleDateFormat`. It only brings needless complication. java.time offers all the functionality you need.

Comment: I get `Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2021-07-23 20:40' could not be parsed at index 10`.

Comment: `new SimpleDateFormat()` without any arguments gave you some default format for your locale, whatever that was. Apparently `7/23/21 11:40 AM`. In any case not the ISO 8601 format that `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME` expects. This caused your exception (and no compile error). But as I said, it was already a troublesome detour that you should avoid completely.

Comment: @Turing85 That answers the question. You convert to `long` before multiplying. We will want to do it after to preserve precision. So `(long) (1627065646.444 * 1000)`. Then we get `2021-07-23T18:40:46.444Z` with decimal fraction on the seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long timestamp = (long) (1627065646.444 * 1000);

        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(timestamp);
        System.out.println(instant);

        ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        LocalDateTime ldt = zdt.toLocalDateTime();
        System.out.println(ldt);

        // A custom format
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/u h:m:s a", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String formatted = dtf.format(zdt);
        System.out.println(formatted);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-07-23T18:40:46.444Z
2021-07-23T18:40:46.444
7/23/2021 6:40:46 PM
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/j5ciw1)

The `Z` in the output is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

#### Apart from this, what else is wrong with your code?

You have done

```
long timestamp = (long) 1627065646.444 * 1000;
```

in which `1627065646.444` will be cast to `long` resulting in `1627065646` and thus the result of the multiplication will be `1627065646000`, not `1627065646444` what you are expecting. You need to cast to `long` after performing the multiplication.

**A valuable comment by Ole V.V.:**

> I’d use `Math.round(1627065646.444 * 1000)` to make sure that
> floating-point inaccuracy is handled.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: I’d use `Math.round(1627065646.444 * 1000)` to make sure that floating point inaccuracy is handled. I haven’t seen any need why we should convert to `LocalDateTime`. A good answer.

Comment: @OleV.V. - Thanks for the suggestion for improvement and the encouraging words.  The result of `1627065646.444 * 1000` is already `1627065646444` and therefore I thought to cast it simply to `long`. However, if the input would have been something like `1627065646.444567`, I would also do it in the way you have suggested.

Comment: You are right: the simple “cast” conversion seems to work for other values too. So using `round()` is only be to assure dumb code readers like me. :-)